# Iterating in JSON using knockout.js

Tags: json, knockout.js

I'm using Knockout.js to realize my web app.
I get data from a database and i use Json to pass data to html page that is rendered through data-bind.

I would like to set the more dynamic possible my app so i would like to iterate through json keys without "hardcoding" the field name

I have the following json: {"id_user":"63","email":"mail@email.it","flag":"1"}
and iterate using:

```
        <table data-bind="foreach:page().users">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text:$data.email"></td>
                <td data-bind="text:$data.flag"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

but i would like to avoid the .email and .flag and using [0] or [1] to reuse this structure for all the models. How can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with a [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html):

```
    <table data-bind="foreach:page().users">
        <tr data-bind="createHeaderRow: $data">
        </tr>  
        <tr data-bind="createTableRow: $data">
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Then create these methods:

```
  ko.bindingHandlers.createHeaderRow = {
      init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
          for (var property in valueAccessor()) {
              $(element).append('<td>' + property + '</td>');
          }
      }
  };
  ko.bindingHandlers.createTableRow = {
      init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
          for (var property in valueAccessor()) {
              $(element).append('<td data-bind="text: ' + property + '"></td>');
          }
      }
  };
```

I've created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gvBXh/5/) to demonstrate it too.

Comment: I like this solutions a lot, but can it be extended further to give you a header row based off of the property names?

Comment: Oh, you could put the two html rows into thead and tbody, if you want to do it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some updated html to get a header and the rows with thead and tbody

```
 <table class="table" >
     <thead  data-bind="with: page().users()[0]">
         <tr data-bind="createHeaderRow: $data">
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody data-bind="foreach: page().users()">
         <tr data-bind="createTableRow: $data">
         </tr>
     </tbody>
 </table>
```